# OpenCV for processing bitmap Images in android

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, image-processing

I have used OPENCV for android to do blob detection in dynamic camera view. I wanted to perform similar functionality for static bitmap images that are present in SDcard of the device. I tried using the *int android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y)*, but its not efficient. It takes so much time to process. 
so, I am wondering whether it is possible to do blob detection in bitmap images using openCV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not do your processing directly on the bitmap because it will be slower.
It is better to convert the bitmap to the opencv Mat structure, process the Mat and then convert it back to bitmap.

To detect blobs with opencv, the best tool available is [Imgproc.findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) You will find a lot of stuff regarding findContours, if you search.

To do the bitmap to mat conversions:

- Bitmap to Mat: [Utils.bitmapToMap](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#bitmapToMat%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20org.opencv.core.Mat%29)
- Mat to Bitmap: [Utils.matToBitmap](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#matToBitmap%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Bitmap.getPixel(x,y), you should really consider getting all pixels into an array and process it this way.

```
Bitmap b=BitmapFactor.decodeFromFile("");
int[] pixels=new int[b.getWidth()*b.getHeight()];
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
       int pixel=pixels[y*b.getWidth()+x];
       // do something with that pixel
    }
}
bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
```